# Angular custom filter causing recursion depth error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

In my Angular app, I have a field called `listing.desired_majors` which is an array of major ids, as an example: `[3, 20, 24]`.

These ids refer to the primary keys of a model of university majors that I have.  I'm trying to write a filter in Angular to convert this array of ids to an array of the majors' titles by iterating through the array and requesting each major's title using the `majors` service factory.  Note that this only needs to happen once--the data being filtered here will never be updated after page render.

However, when I include the filter in a template, I get a recursive error that goes ad infinitum, and I can't figure out why.  What's particularly odd is not only that it throws a depth error, but that the browser then continues to throw this error again and again until it crashes.  I've refactored the filter four or five times now, and I've tried including a `bind-once` directive I found on Stack Overflow, but that didn't help either.  Can you tell what the issue is here?  Is it that Angular keeps calling the filter over and over again because the data is bound using `{{ }}`?  If that is the issue, why is this causing a depth error?

The template:

```
<dd ng-show="listing.desired_majors">{{ listing.desired_majors | majorIdsToObjects:'title' | joinBy:','}}</dd>
```

The filter:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .filter('majorIdsToobjects', ['majors', function (majors) {
        return function (items, returnAttr) {
            var filtered = [];

            var getMajor = function (major) {
                majors.get({majorId: major},
                    function (res) {
                        if (returnAttr == null) {
                            filtered.push(res);
                        } else {
                            filtered.push(res[returnAttr]);
                        }
                    }, function (res) {
                        //TODO: handle error
                    });
            };

            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                getMajor(item);
            });

            return filtered;
        }
    }]);
```

For reference, here is the `joinBy` filter:

```coffee
# this is in coffeescript
angular.module('campusJobApp').filter 'joinBy', ->
  (input, delimiter) -> (input || []).join delimiter || ', '
```

Here is a screenshot of the error.  Keep in mind that this error appears hundreds of times until the browser crashes:
[image]

Comment: You cannot return a list from a filter with new objects every time that its called. This results in infinite digests.  You need to cache your transformed list, and then filter on the transformed data. For example, iterate over the original array, transform each item, and store it in another array and cache it locally so that  the next time its called it uses the same transformed array. In your filter logic, filter the transformed array (not the original array)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this makes sense and confirms my suspicion that what I was trying to do isn't possible--but now I know why.  If you submit as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It may be possible, I don't know the full context about how you're using your filters. Adding 'track by' in your filter may actually fix the issue since it will no longer rely on reference equality to determine if an item has changed (in other words, using track by may allow you to have new instances in the filtered list without angular treating it as if the item has changed). If you post a simplified fiddle and add it to your original post, it may help with the answer.